# Issue Calling JAX-WS Clients Simultaneously

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws

I have two separate JAX-WS (Metro) clients consuming two web services exposed by the same server/port -
Say www.test.com:1234/SomeService1 and www.test.com:1234/SomeService2

Both are protected by BASIC authentication.

```
    BindingProvider bindingProvider = (BindingProvider)port;
    bindingProvider.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, endpoint);
    bindingProvider.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY, username);
    bindingProvider.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, password);
```

When calling either service individually, everything works fine.
However, when both services are called in close temporal proximity to one another, I receive an HTTP 401 from one of the calls, and it appears that no username/password is sent with the request.
The other call succeeds with no problem.

Its worth noting that when both services are NOT exposed on the same server/port, everything is fine. (e.g. www.test.com:1234 & www.test.com:4321)

I'm at a loss to explain the behavior - any advice?

Edit: Additional Information
We're running on top of spring, but not using any of its DI capabilities (this is a very old legacy app that was shoehorned onto Spring at some point)

The WebService provider assures me they're capable of concurrent processing.

Comment: Sounds like a threadsafety concern. Stubs and most of the constructs associated with them (BindingProviders e.t.c.) are not threadsafe. Beyond that, you should look into bugs with JAX-WS impl you're running

Comment: I had thought that as well, but its two entirely separate BindingProviders.   Is there a chance they're sharing implementation details in the JAX-WS framework?

Comment: You should provide more detail about your execution context - are you running any DI framework (spring, cdi etc)? Are you in control of the web service, so as to guarantee that concurrent request processing is supported by the web service?